# List.Contains in Unity C# not working

Tags: c#, list, unity-game-engine, contains

I'm working on a project in which a player character, sphere and a cylinder exist on a plane.

The way it should work is that The Character detects the sphere and can 'pick it up' by sending the name of the sphere to a list and then destroying the object. The Name (`Sphere` in this case) is then checked for using `inventory.Contains("Sphere")` when the character interacts with the box, and if the key is in the inventory, it will 'unlock', however regardless of whether the sphere is in the inventory or not, the box is locked.

Here is the Code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class RayCasting : MonoBehaviour 
{
   float  rayCoeff;
   RaycastHit hit;
   List<string> inventory = new List<string>();

   // Use this for initialization
   void Start () 
   {
      rayCoeff = 3f;
   }

void Cast()
{
    Debug.DrawRay (transform.position, Vector3.right * rayCoeff, Color.red);
    Debug.DrawRay (transform.position, Vector3.right * -rayCoeff, Color.red);
    Debug.DrawRay (transform.position, Vector3.forward * rayCoeff, Color.red);
    Debug.DrawRay (transform.position, Vector3.forward * -rayCoeff, Color.red);

    if (Physics.Raycast (transform.position, Vector3.forward, out hit, rayCoeff, 1<<8)) {
        if(hit.collider.tag == "Interactable") {
            //Debug.Log ("Front Scan with collider!, Found Thing.");
            if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.E)) {
                string inventoryClaim = hit.collider.ToString();
                inventory.Add(inventoryClaim);
                Destroy(hit.collider.gameObject);

            }
        }
    } 
    else if (Physics.Raycast (transform.position, new Vector3(0, 0, -1), out hit, rayCoeff, 1<<8)) {
        if(hit.collider.tag == "Interactable") {
            //Debug.Log ("Back Scan with collider!, Found Thing.");
            if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.E)) {
                string inventoryClaim = hit.collider.ToString();
                inventory.Add(inventoryClaim);
                Destroy(hit.collider.gameObject);

            }
        }
    }
    else if (Physics.Raycast (transform.position, Vector3.right, out hit, rayCoeff, 1<<8)) {
        if(hit.collider.tag == "Interactable") {
            //Debug.Log ("Right Scan with collider!, Found Thing.");
            if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.E)) {
                string inventoryClaim = hit.collider.ToString();
                inventory.Add(inventoryClaim);
                Destroy(hit.collider.gameObject);

            }
        }
    }
    else if (Physics.Raycast (transform.position, new Vector3(-1, 0, 0), out hit, rayCoeff, 1<<8)) {
        if(hit.collider.tag == "Interactable") {
            //Debug.Log ("Left Scan with collider!, Found Thing.");
            if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.E)) {
                string inventoryClaim = hit.collider.ToString();
                inventory.Add(inventoryClaim);
                Destroy(hit.collider.gameObject);

            }
        }
        else if (hit.collider.tag == "Cylinder"){
            if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.E)) {
                if(inventory.Contains("Sphere")) {
                    Debug.Log("Hooray!");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}



// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    Cast ();
}
}
```

There is no error, just a lack of recognition.

Comment: Please, read the tag description before adding it.

Comment: what happens when you step through the code yourself.. can you tell us the line that the issue is happening in..? what or where is this defined `hit.collider` also work on reformatting your code snippet

Comment: Is it because `hit.collider.ToString()` is not actually equal to "Sphere"

Answer (score 1):

Extending Vlad's comment... calling hit.collider.ToString() will return something like "Sphere (UnityEngine.SphereCollider)" – some kind of string ID of the collider saying that this is a sphere collider sitting on a game object called Sphere. 
So if you want the name of the game object that the hit collider sits on, you would write

```
string inventoryClaim = hit.collider.name;
```

The variable "name" will refer to the name of the game object that the component (in this case the collider) sits on.